# Unable to get the file name of excel from a folder using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am doing a web scraping project using excel VBA. So the code open the webpage and after few navigation and clicks, an .CSV file is downloaded to the downloads folder. Now I need a VBA code to open that .CSV file. The downloads folder will always be empty and as I will delete all the files present before initiating the code. I am using selenium and Firefox for automation. I cannot change any other browser as the portal is restricted for other browsers. I believe Firefox does not open .CSV file automatically once downloaded. I have searched for the same here but all I see is to get the list of file names from a folder, instead I need .CSV file name to be added in a string or variant so I could work with it.

Comment: *The downloads folder will always be empty... all I see is to get the list of file names from a folder... I need .CSV file name* - you're answering your own question.

Comment: Here is a link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31414106/get-list-of-excel-files-in-a-folder-using-vba where the answer is In a form of function. I need VBA code because I will have only one file in the downloads folders.