# VBA Listing Files & Folders With Hyperlinks

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I found a fantasic little macro on this site that lists all the folders, sub-folders and files along with indenting and grouping the list when transferred to the sheet but am having a little difficulty trying to modify it. *(I'm a little new to VBA but am pretty intimidated by this complex-looking macro ahah)*
If anyone would be able to assist or point out some ideas it really would be greatly appreciated. :)

a. I'm trying to figure out what parts of the code I change or add to rather then listing the path in the cells list the folder and file name instead

b. similarly, I'm also trying to find the part where I can change to add the folder/file name to include a hyperlink containing the folder/file path. I know that you use *".Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=, Address:=FolderName & "" & FileName, TextToDisplay:=FileName"* but am a little unsure which lines to use this on

c. I guess the trickiest one, to change it so it uses the select folder popup using the Application FileDialog function "msoFileDialogFilePicker" but really would have no idea how to change this without breaking the rest of the whole code.

```
''--found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56395005/excel-vba-list-files-grouped-by-folder/73669234#73669234

Public Sub ShowFilePaths()
    Dim rootFolder As String
    rootFolder = SelectFolder
    If rootFolder = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

    '--- quick fixup if needed
    rootFolder = rootFolder & IIf(Right$(rootFolder, 1) = "\", vbNullString, "\")

    Dim pathArray As Variant
    pathArray = GetAllFiles(rootFolder)

    Dim folderGroups As Object
    Set folderGroups = BuildFolderDictionary(rootFolder, pathArray)

    '--- when debugging, this block just clears the worksheet to make it
    '    easier to rerun and test the code
    On Error Resume Next
    With Sheet1
        .UsedRange.ClearOutline
        .UsedRange.Clear
        .Outline.SummaryRow = xlAbove
    End With
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    '--- copy the array to the worksheet
    Const START_ROW As Long = 6
    Dim pathRange As Range
    Set pathRange = Sheet1.Range("A" & START_ROW).Resize(UBound(pathArray), 1)
    pathRange = pathArray
    pathRange.Font.Color = RGB(237, 125, 49)
    pathRange.Font.Bold = True
    pathRange.Font.Italic = True

    '------ now apply the indention levels to each line on the sheet
    '       and group the same rows
    Const MAX_GROUP_LEVEL As Long = 8
    Dim rowGroup As Variant
    Dim level As Long
    Dim folderData As Variant
    Dim theseRows As String
    For Each rowGroup In folderGroups
        folderData = Split(folderGroups(rowGroup), ",")
        theseRows = folderData(0)
        level = folderData(1)
        With pathRange.rows(theseRows)
            .IndentLevel = level
            If level < MAX_GROUP_LEVEL Then
                .Group
            End If
        End With
    Next rowGroup
End Sub

Private Function SelectFolder() As String
    '--- returns the user-selected folder as a string
    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select Folder", 0, 17)
    If Not objFolder Is Nothing Then
        SelectFolder = objFolder.self.Path
    End If
End Function

Private Function GetAllFiles(ByVal rootPath As String, _
                             Optional onlyFolders As Boolean = False) As Variant
    '--- returns a sorted array of all filepaths in the given directory path
    Dim dirOptions As String
    If onlyFolders Then
        dirOptions = """ /a:d-h-s /b /s"
    Else
        dirOptions = """ /a:-h-s /b /s"
    End If
    Dim fOut() As String
    fOut = Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").exec("cmd /c dir """ & _
                                                    rootPath & _
                                                    dirOptions).StdOut.ReadAll, _
                 vbNewLine)
    QuickSort fOut, LBound(fOut), UBound(fOut)

    '--- the pathArray skips the first position from the fOut array
    '    because it's always blank, but add the root folder as the first entry
    Dim pathArray As Variant
    ReDim pathArray(1 To UBound(fOut) + 1, 1 To 1)
    pathArray(1, 1) = rootPath
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To UBound(fOut) + 1
        pathArray(i, 1) = fOut(i - 1)
    Next i
    GetAllFiles = pathArray
End Function

Private Function BuildFolderDictionary(ByVal root As String, _
                                       ByRef paths As Variant) As Object
    Dim folders As Object
    Set folders = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    '--- scan all paths and create a dictionary of each folder and subfolder
    '    noting which items (rows) map into each dictionary
    Dim folder As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(paths) To UBound(paths)
        Dim pos1 As Long
        If Not IsEmpty(paths(i, 1)) Then
            pos1 = InStrRev(paths(i, 1), "\")   'find the last folder separator
            folder = Left$(paths(i, 1), pos1)
            If Not folders.Exists(folder) Then
                '--- new (sub)folder, create a new entry
                folders.Add folder, CStr(i) & ":" & CStr(i)
            Else
                '--- extisting (sub)folder, add to the row range
                Dim rows As String
                rows = folders(folder)
                rows = Left$(rows, InStr(1, rows, ":"))
                rows = rows & CStr(i)
                folders(folder) = rows
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    '--- final fixup: the root folder group should always encompass all
    '    the entries (runs from the second row to the end)...
    '    and we'll also determine the indent level using the first entry
    '    as the baseline (level 1).  stored as "rows,level" e.g. "2:7,1"
    Dim rootSlashes As Long
    rootSlashes = Len(root) - Len(Replace(root, "\", "")) - 1
    folders(root) = "2:" & UBound(paths) & ",1"

    Dim slashes As Long
    folder = folders.Keys
    For i = 1 To UBound(folder)
        slashes = Len(folder(i)) - Len(Replace(folder(i), "\", ""))
        folders(folder(i)) = folders(folder(i)) & "," & _
                                     CStr(slashes - rootSlashes)
    Next i

    For Each folder In folders
        Debug.Print folder & " - " & folders(folder)
    Next folder

    Set BuildFolderDictionary = folders
End Function

Private Sub QuickSort(ByRef Field() As String, ByVal LB As Long, ByVal UB As Long)
    '--- from https://stackoverflow.com/a/152333/4717755
    Dim P1 As Long, P2 As Long, Ref As String, TEMP As String

    P1 = LB
    P2 = UB
    Ref = Field((P1 + P2) / 2)

    Do
        Do While (Field(P1) < Ref)
            P1 = P1 + 1
        Loop

        Do While (Field(P2) > Ref)
            P2 = P2 - 1
        Loop

        If P1 <= P2 Then
            TEMP = Field(P1)
            Field(P1) = Field(P2)
            Field(P2) = TEMP

            P1 = P1 + 1
            P2 = P2 - 1
        End If
    Loop Until (P1 > P2)

    If LB < P2 Then Call QuickSort(Field, LB, P2)
    If P1 < UB Then Call QuickSort(Field, P1, UB)
End Sub
```

Comment: For adding the hyperlinks: The range that contains all of the exported paths is `pathRange`. So you would need to loop through `pathRange` and add the hyperlinks to each cell in that range.

Comment: For changing the output: the values that get pasted into the worksheet are in `pathArray`. Which gets its values from `GetAllFiles`. You just need to change the output of `GetAllFiles`.  In that function, `fOut` is using Shell to get a list of files, you'll need to change that to return the data you want, which will then be returned from `GetAllFiles` into `pathArray` and pasted into `pathRange`

Comment: For making this work based on a user-selected folder: that's actually the easiest part. You just need to change how `rootFolder` gets its value. Currently it uses the `SelectFolder` function, but if you want to use `FileDialog` you just need to do that instead of `SelectFolder`

Comment: Hi @Toddleson, thanks for the reply! :) 
I've been able to add some hyperlinks to the pasted `pathRange` using `ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=pathRange, Address:=rootFolder, TextToDisplay:=rootFolder, ScreenTip:="Click To Open" ` but when clicked this only opens to the folder and not the file. Instead of the `rootFolder` what should I be using for the `Address:=` instead? 
I'm also struggling a bit with adding the folder and file name `TextToDisplay:=` any suggestions? 
Apologies if it's obvious, still learning lots. Thanks again for the help! :)

Comment: Each cell of `pathRange` gets its value from a corresponding element of `pathArray`. For example if `pathArray` were `{A, B, C}`, cell 1 of `pathRange` would be `A`, cell 2 would be `B`, and cell 3 would be `C`. This is because your line of code `pathRange = pathArray` makes this happen. So if you want each cell of `pathRange` to be a hyperlink whose address is the file path, you just need to loop through each cell of `pathRange` and add a hyperlink with `Address:= pathArray(x)` where x is the loop element.

Comment: If I were to guess how it could be written: `For x = 1 to pathRange.Cells.Count: Activesheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=pathRange.Cells(x), Address:=pathArray(x), ...`

Comment: ok thanks for that. I'll have to do some more research on how to achieve this as I wouldn't really know how to but I'll let you know how I get on. :)