# Open multiple Excel files based on partial file name

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to select multiple files (as shown); eg. "DataSource Quality", "DataSource Security", "DataSource Shipping", "DataSource Warehouse".

[image]

To add on, if the file name selected is "DataSource Quality 2020", etc, it should still be a valid selection. Meaning to say, so long the filename contains the names as shown in the screenshot above, it should still be considered correct.

However, if any one of the files selected are wrong (wrong partial file name), there should be a message box that says "**No/Wrong file selected**".

```
Dim hasRun As Boolean

Sub RunOnlyOnce()

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    If hasRun = False Then
        
        Dim fNameAndPath As Variant
        fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="All Files (*.*), *.*", Title:="Select Files To Be Opened", MultiSelect:=True)
        Debug.Print fNameAndPath
        Debug.Print Dir(fNameAndPath)

        If Dir(fNameAndPath) = "DataSource.xlsx" Then
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=fNameAndPath
            hasRun = True
            Exit Sub
        Else
            MsgBox "No/Wrong file selected. ", vbExclamation, "Oops!"
            ThisWorkbook.Saved = False
            Application.Quit

        End If
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `If Dir(fNameAndPath) Like "DataSource*" Then`

Comment: Hi Peter, I've encountered some problem over this line of code: `Debug.Print fNameAndPath`. This line of code used to work with only SINGLE file, I don't think it work with single file anymore; is there any way around this?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10382861/4717755) to see how to loop through the files in a directory.

Comment: Hello Peter, thanks for the link! From the thread, it seems like the files are store in some folder... In my case, I would like the code to just verify the file names according to the files being selected; not folder path dependent. Hope that helps to clarify if I am unclear before. Thank you so much once again! (Ps, still a VBA newbie here, please pardon me if I sound stupid)

Comment: Hi @JoshNg, I think you problem is due to the `MultiSelect:=True` argument. According to [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getopenfilename) on the _GetOpenFilename_ method, if the multi select argument is set to true, you result will be an "array of the selected file names". So you need to loop into your array of file names to display all of them (even if you selected only one).

Comment: Oh right, thanks! I'll check that out in a moment :) in the mean time, if someone could rectify the error before I'm able to, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my code:

```
Sub SubOpenDataSourceFiles()

    'Declarations.
    Dim WrkMotherWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim VarFiles As Variant
    Dim IntCounter01 As Integer
    Dim StrFileName As String
    Dim StrMarker As String

    'Setting variables.
    StrMarker = "DataSource"
    Set WrkMotherWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

    'Request the user what files to open.
    VarFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="All Files (*.*), *.*", _
                                           Title:="Select Files To Be Opened", _
                                           MultiSelect:=True _
                                          )

    'Checking if it has been selected any file.
    On Error GoTo No_File_Selected
    IntCounter01 = UBound(VarFiles)
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Scrolling through the files.
    For IntCounter01 = 1 To UBound(VarFiles)

        'Setting the variable in order to analyse the file name.
        StrFileName = Split(VarFiles(IntCounter01), "\")(UBound(Split(VarFiles(IntCounter01), "\")))

        'Checking if the left part of the file name differs from StrMarker.
        If Left(StrFileName, Len(StrMarker)) <> StrMarker Then
            'If it does differ, a message box pops up.
            MsgBox "Unauthorized file.", vbExclamation, StrFileName
        Else
            'If it doesn't differ, it opens the file (assuming it's not a corrupted file).
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=CStr(VarFiles(IntCounter01))
        End If

    Next

    'Activating WrkMotherWorkbook.
    WrkMotherWorkbook.Activate

No_File_Selected:

End Sub
```

It might not be as elegant as Gangula's one, but still it should work. Only point: i've maintained your "all files" preference when opening the files. Still i'd suggest to filter it to .xlsm or .xls or whatever kind of excel files you are supposed to open. Just like Gangula's did.

Comment: Thanks mate!! Will check it out in a while once I got on my PC.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a Function to get a list of all the files in a folder. There is already a answer in SO for that at the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31428399/6908282

Below is the same code.

```html
Public Function listfiles(ByVal sPath As String)
    
    Dim vaArray     As Variant
    Dim i           As Integer
    Dim oFile       As Object
    Dim oFSO        As Object
    Dim oFolder     As Object
    Dim oFiles      As Object

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sPath)
    Set oFiles = oFolder.Files

    If oFiles.Count = 0 Then Exit Function

    ReDim vaArray(1 To oFiles.Count)
    i = 1
    For Each oFile In oFiles
        vaArray(i) = oFile.Name
        i = i + 1

    Next

    listfiles = vaArray
    
  End Function
```

After this is defined you can use this function in a procedure to loop through all the files if they match you criteria using the [LIKE Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator) and open the files that match the criteria. See example below

```
Public Sub abc()
Dim Path As String, file As Variant, i As Integer

Path = "D:\Parent Folder\Sub Folder"
i = 1
For Each file In listfiles(Path)
 If file Like "test*" And file Like "*.xlsm" Then MsgBox file  ' replace "MsgBox file" with "Workbooks.Open Path & "\" & file"
    i = i + 1
 Next


End Sub
```

Note: In the above code make sure to edit 4 things

1. "**Path**" variable
2. "**test***" condition. Replace test with DataSource if all you files start with DataSource. DO NOT remove the "*" as this is a wild card match to match anything after that.
3. "***.xlsm**". This is to check the file type of the file. Change xlsm to xlsx or xlsm or remove the condition entirely if you want all excel files.
4. Currently, the procedure only shows a Msgbox for all the matching files, you need to replace "**MsgBox file**" with "**Workbooks.Open Path & "\" & file**"

Check the [LIKE Operator documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator)  to know more about comparing string patterns.

Comment: Hey Gangula! Thanks for the answer! I'll try it out later on, so sorry for the delay in my response. Really appreciate it!!

Comment: Hi Gangula! Happy Easter to you in advance :) I've tried the codes; for this part `For Each file In listfiles(Path)`, there's an error: Sub or Function not defined. Am I missing anything over here? Thanks!

Comment: There are 2 sets of codes that I have in my answer. You need to have both. One is a Function **listfiles(ByVal sPath As String)** in the "Show Code Snippet" drop-down and the other is **Public Sub abc()** which is visible.

Comment: Thank you Gangula! I have decided to use Evil's Blue Monkey's in my current project and yours in my next! Just because you've got a robust code for this scenario. Thanks a million mate!!

Answer (score 1):

I have modified you code to give an example for discerning between the different filename requirements when selecting multiple files:

```
Sub OpenOnlyValidFiles()
    fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="All Files (*.*), *.*", Title:="Select Files To Be Opened", MultiSelect:=True)

    AllFilesAreValid = True
    For Each FullPathAndName In fNameAndPath  'Test all files to see if they meet requirements
        ' Test only filename and not the path
        fName = Split(FullPathAndName, Application.PathSeparator)(UBound(Split(FullPathAndName, Application.PathSeparator)))
        If Not (fName Like "DataSource Quality*") And _
           Not (fName Like "DataSource Security*") And _
           Not (fName Like "DataSource Shipping*") And _
           Not (fName Like "DataSource Warehouse*") And _
           Not (fName Like "GoodFile*") Then
            AllFilesAreValid = False
        End If
     Next

    If AllFilesAreValid Then 'If all files meet the requirements then open them in Notepad
        For Each FullPathAndName In fNameAndPath
            Shell "NOTEPAD.EXE " & FullPathAndName
        Next
        MsgBox (UBound(fNameAndPath) & " valid files found and opened in notepad")
    Else
        MsgBox ("At least one file was not valid. No files opened.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Create a folder to test with files in it like:

```
DataSource Excluded Stuff.txt
DataSource Quality.txt
DataSource Security.txt
DataSource Security 2020.txt
DataSource Shipping.txt
DataSource Warehouse.txt
DataSource Warehouse 2019.txt
DataSource Warehouse 2020.txt
GoodFile.txt
BadFile.txt
GoodFile 2020.txt
BadFile 2020.txt
```

You can modify the code to check for '.xlsx' or ".xlsm" extensions or to let it open any valid files found instead of rejecting if even one file is invalid.

Comment: Thank you LanchDango! I really really appreciate the help! I will definitely include your suggestion in my next coming project!! Thanks a million again! If I could give bounty to everyone here, I WILL!